# Best way to download large files from a server

Tags: download, rsync, bittorrent-sync

I have a remote server running the last ubuntu's version. I was wondering which is the best, secure and easiest way to download large files ( > 1GB) from this server.

The download MUST be:

1. Encrypted
2. With resume support (because of my slow download speed)

At this moment I'm using bittorrent sync and it works pretty well. The problem is that it is not open sources and I cannnot trust it 100%.

Which other ways do you recommend? rsync? scp I dont think has resume support..

NOTE: I only need to download files, I dont need a way to keep files and/or foldes

EDIT: I have no webserver installed on this server. So I cant download these files using wget, curl and something..

Answer (score 0):

You mention it's a server, so why not use `wget`? Just use `wget -c http://example.com/file` to resume the download.

Alternatively, `rsync` is also an option with the `--partial` option.

Comment: @gaggina, then I'd use `rsync --partial /path/to/source /path/to/destination`. `scp` doesn't have support for resuming transfers.